# Using MS Access and VBA to update (Field codes: Database) field in Ms Word Document

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word

Ms Word Database field inserts the results of a database query in a Word table.

I want to populate a Table in ms word using VBA , I already did using VBA MsAccess & MsWord bookmark , the template from the data make the document very difficult to maintain. I found MSword have the option insert database , and  allow you to actualize the data in msaccess and preserve the preformating during updates .
The following **Database field** code results from a query from my Access database through ODBC using the Database command:

> { DATABASE  \d "C:\My Data Sources\To test World.odc" \c
>   "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;Extended
>   Properties=\"DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=H:\CIP
>   BOOK\CIP2.accdb;DefaultDir=H:\CIP BOOK;DriverId=25;FIL=MS
>   Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;\";Initial Catalog=H:\CIP
>   BOOK\CIP2.accdb" \s "SELECT `Description`, `TA`, `Entry Title`,
>   `Memo` FROM `qryTransactions ExtendedWordFill_test` WHERE
>   ((*`Project_id` = 'PCP13ZOOA06*'))" \l "26" \b "191" \h  * MERGEFORMAT
>   }

First  my wdFieldDatabase have  Fields(Index), where Index is the index number(Field object). The index number represents the position of the field in the selection, range, or document

Second I find a Fields.Add Method (Word)
This example if to add  a field ListNum

```
 Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _ 
 Type:=**wdFieldListNum**, Text:="\s 3"
```

What I want is tu update using VBA  the Code in  *(Field codes: Database field)* base on the index location and change the ( *Project_id = 'PCP13ZOOA06*). Other alternative can be add the field Database in specific range , location of the document using creating the code in VBA.  I want to manage this from access , the idea is to create status reports with tables of expense  for more than 2oo projects.

[Field codes: Database field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-Database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but wouldn't something like this work for you?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateDatabaseField()
    Dim fldTarget As Field: Set fldTarget = ActiveDocument.Fields(1) ' TODO: Find your field based on your knowledge of your document
    Dim strProjectIdNew As String: strProjectIdNew = "123456" ' TODO: Determine new project code

    Dim strCodeOld As String: strCodeOld = fldTarget.Code.Text
    Dim ixBegin As Long: ixBegin = InStr(1, strCodeOld, "Project_id") + Len("Project_id")
    Dim ixEnd As Long: ixEnd = InStr(ixBegin, strCodeOld, ")")
    Dim strCodeNew As String: strCodeNew = Left(strCodeOld, ixBegin) & "='" & strProjectIdNew & "'" & Mid(strCodeOld, ixEnd)
    fldTarget.Code.Text = strCodeNew
End Sub
```

The final code:

```
Public Sub UpdateDatabaseField()
Dim fldTarget As Field: Set fldTarget = ActiveDocument.Fields(1) ' TODO: Find your field based on your knowledge of your document
Dim strProjectIdNew As String: strProjectIdNew = "PCP13ZOOA08" ' TODO: Determine new project code

Dim strCodeOld As String: strCodeOld = fldTarget.Code.Text
Dim ixBegin As Long: ixBegin = InStr(1, strCodeOld, "Project_id") + Len("Project_id") - 0
Dim ixEnd As Long: ixEnd = InStr(ixBegin, strCodeOld, ")")
Dim strCodeNew As String: strCodeNew = Left(strCodeOld, ixBegin) & "='" & strProjectIdNew & "'" & Mid(strCodeOld, ixEnd)
fldTarget.Code.Text = strCodeNew
ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Update
```

End Sub

Comment: Is work , I only modify the Len("Project_id") - 1 to Len("Project_id") - 0